# Не сработал gitignore

Tags: git, phpstorm

Подскажите в гит залез файл из phpstorm:

```
$ git status
On branch merged-sitename
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/merged-sitename'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
```

В .gitignore я добавил строку :

```
assets
.idea/*
```

Но файл все равно в обновлениях 
Разве формат .gitignore неправилен?
И можно ли убрать этот файл из изменей командами git и как?

И можно ли убрать файл из изменений непосредствеено в phpstorm?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz8oF.jpg
Я не нашел такой возможности?

Спасибо!

Comment: попробуй `.gitignore` просто `.idea` ...... из изменений гита можно через revert сделать ......... в phpstorm в настройках проекта через `exclude` директории из проекта

Comment: Мне помогла команда 
git rm --cached .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml

Comment: @mstdmstd тогда отметьте ответ Александра как правильный — галочка слева от ответа, под стрелками.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
>
>        new file:   .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
> ```

вы добавили этот файл в [индекс (staging area)](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch07.html#_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_git), либо выполнив команду `git add ...` либо с помощью вашего *ide*.

убрать (unstage) этот файл из индекса, как прямо и написано в подсказке, можно командой:

```
$ git reset HEAD .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
```

другой вариант:

```
$ git rm --cached .idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
```

---

> ```
> .idea/*
> ```
>
> Разве формат .gitignore неправилен?

всё правильно (хотя можно и сократить до `.idea`). просто вы добавили файл в индекс **до того**, как внесли эту строку в файл `.gitignore`. и «сам собой» файл из индекса не «пропадёт», сколько бы вы ни правили файл `.gitignore`. нужно его явно удалить оттуда (см. выше).

сейчас, **после того**, как эта строка внесена, добавить файл из каталога `.idea` «просто так» не получится:

```
$ git add .idea/file
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.idea/file
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

только с дополнительной опцией `-f` (от слова force):

```
$ git add -f .idea/file
```